# checkBox не работает

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Не могу разобраться почему не работает checkBox. Нужно чтобы при нажатом чекбоксе музыка была включена, а при отжатом отключена.

```
public class Stage extends Activity {
    CheckBox musicOff;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stage);
        musicOff = findViewById(R.id.musicCb);

        if (musicOff.isChecked()) {
            startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        } else {
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо повесить слушатель на чекбокс. Он чекед листенер или как его там

Comment: Если вы нашли решение самостоятельно, то оформите его как ответ (ответить на собственный вопрос). Не пишите решение проблемы в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Так работает:

```
public void checkBoxClicked (View view) {
    if (musicOff.isChecked()) {
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    } else {
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
}
```